# Damning problem

Tags: word-usage, formal-language, register, academic-writing

As a task at my university, I am proofreading and commenting on an academic paper of my groupmate. I came across the word combination "damning problem" in the following context:

> The most damning problem within the model is...

I am wondering whether the word "damning" is formal enough to write it in an academic paper. According to a number of online dictionaries, it has quite a usual meaning:

> (of evidence or a report) suggesting very strongly that someone is guilty of a crime or has made a serious mistake

However, my search in the context brought me to some newspaper articles that, I imagine, could use strong colloquial expressions, and self-development books. Besides, it sounds to me like a curse "damn". All in all, the paper that I am annotating is mistakenly written in a rather informal way. This fact makes me suspicious about even slightly informal expressions.

Since I am not a native speaker, I would like to ask for the help of the ELL community. Is the expression "a damning problem" neutral enough to use it in an academic context?

Comment: Is it merely a bad problem or will the offspring of the offender be held in contempt for generations?  Serious question.

Comment: A sentence fragment doesn't provide much context.

Comment: `damning` is certainly a 'strong' word, but certainly not a 'bad' or swear word.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that "damning" is not a curse word in this context, but merely means "leading to condemnation" and so is not inappropriate **in itself** in formal writing. I further agree that it would greatly help if we were provided more than a fragment of a sentence. But I am quite disturbed by the word "within."

Can a model, let alone some part of a model, condemn something? I doubt it. It may contradict something, but I do not think a model has legal or moral authority. So "damning" may be an inappropriate word to express whatever meaning is intended.

However, the intended meaning may have to do with "condemning" the model or some part of the model for some reason. In that case, the sentence makes no sense. It should say something like "the most damning fault **with** the model." A model is good or bad; we do not say it is a good model except for the parts that are bad. I personally would not use "damning" here because it implies moral fault, but that is a style choice and so a matter of opinion. But "damning within" just seems meaningless.

Comment: "_In the representation of the war as a self-sustaining bureaucratic and technological machine, these writers presented **a damning model** of the workings of the modern material order._"

Comment: "_Barbara Ching chooses **another, equally damning model** for Tosches's stature, noting that his book Country: Living Legends and Dying Metaphors in America's Biggest Music is "written with all the tedious bravado of a frat boy who knows..._"

Comment: "_Wharton used the club movement's rich conceptual vocabulary and **its damning model** of social categorization to plot Lily Bart's fluctuating relation to an asymmetrical social..._" Just to list a few examples from Google Books, all proper academic writing. It seems some people are too quick to condemn damning

Comment: I made no objection to the word "damning." I do object to the idea of a model with moral authority. Three examples of over-inflated academic bumpf do not persuade me otherwise.

Comment: `within the model` is perfectly good grammar, only the most trivial academic models will it be so simple as to render it incorrect, otherwise its reasonable to assume that there are many facets, and this only refers to one of them.

Comment: @MikeBrockington I might agree with that if a model has an error that is immaterial, but if there are multiple "damning errors," I'd not view it as a useful model. Is it the math that is wrong, the logic, or the empirical bases from which it is abstracted?

Comment: The reviewer certainly doesn't think that the model is a great one, quite possibly he does not indeed, think that it is a useful model. Without the full context we cannot be sure, but clearly leaning in that direction.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Yes, it is hard to be sure that an answer or comment is completely on the mark when the question itself contains so little context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its meaning is clear with the context you've given us. I would take it to mean that the problem referred to is the worst problem, and also that the writer is neither writing formally enough for an academic work nor being careful enough with his words.

The word "damn" has religious connotations; the earliest uses I'm aware of, in the Bible, refer to an action by God against someone who had transgressed His laws or disobeyed him; people who were damned were condemned to Hell. I always thought the Biblical prohibition against "taking the Lord's name in vain" referred to an individual assuming God's prerogative of damning someone.

I've certainly heard of "the most damning evidence", usually in reference to evidence of a serious crime, and did not assume they were talking about God in those cases.

Comment: A book, a sentence, words can all be damning without religious implications.